# Is adding more details on another person's question good practice?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I came through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771825/java-string-split-by-semicolon#comment47674715_29771825) question where the user trying to split a string by semicolon. The string was

```
String phrase = "‫;‪14/May/2015‬‬ ‫‪FC‬‬ ‫‪Barcelona‬‬ ‫‪VS.‬‬ ‫‪Real‬‬ ‫‪Madrid";
```

which contains some hidden characters.

Some other users were saying that this code won't compile(which is different behaviour described by OP) and were doubting the question, so I created demo of that code in Ideone and added it to the question with some extra print statements to explain the question in more detail.

My question is whether it is a good practice to add more details to another person's question in order to get them more responses and clarifying the problem more? Or should we only edit question for formatting and spelling mistakes?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Be *super* careful when doing this, as you don't want to change the question.

Because it's so easy to accidentally obscure the issue, changes like this are usually discouraged. That said, if you aren't changing the question, or the code, go right ahead! This is much safer if you have verification of your code/details in the comments as well.

Comment: When doing *"invasive"* edits, I think it is a good safety net to add a comment explicitly requesting a review from the OP -- pointing out that she/he could revert that edit or edit the question further if needed.